# How to satisfy Aggregations and Joins in HTTP microservices?

Tags: sql, mapreduce, microservices, aggregation

We have a SaaS product which we have decided to apart the product/service buying logic (Shopping cart, Products, Orders, Payments, Transactions) from the main application by wrapping it around an HTTP microservice due to some reasons (Accounting needs, Maintainability, Testability, Tech Stack and...)

In the ecommerce microservice we only use the global customerID as the root. What is the proper way to perform cross queries with our main application (Mostly for unexpected BI needs), For instance:

- Listing all companies that their employees are more than 5 people and have bought "X" product in the last 6 Months. (Problem is that the ecommerce data store does not know anything about the customer attributes)
- Listing top companies by payment size with their company name (Problem is that the ecommerce microservice does not know anything about the customer's company name).

For application-level needs we can Get the final customerIds and mix them (For example perform a `where in` query in SQL).

What is the proper way to handle such a problems for business reports (Which work with the whole data) and instant aggregation queries?

Comment: So, you have more than one microservices and you want to build reports that contain data from those microservices?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU yes.

Comment: You can use events. The microservices emit events when something change (i.e. `CompanyCreated`, `EmployeeStartedWorkingOnACompany`, `OrderPlaced` and so on) and the Reports microservice register to those events and builds a complete and specific readmodel (in a `NoSql` databse - no need for joins), i.e. `AllCompaniesWithEmployeesAndTheirPurchases`